# Apply Custom Loss in Keras by getting batch_size

Tags: keras

I have a python package/function which takes two numpy arrays and returns a value. I want to use this value as my loss in keras. How do I infer batch size to compute average loss (while using egar execution). Using the below implementation gives me error

```
 __index__ returned non-int (type NoneType)

import myloss
def customLoss(yt,yp):
   loss=0
   for i in range(yp.shape[0]):  #get batch size; yp is of shape (batch,200,1)
      loss = loss + myloss(yt[i,:],yp[i,:])
   return loss/yp.shape[0]

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=customLoss)
```